# Python: PCM audio manipulation - noisy left channel while using struct

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is one of my first codes. I wrote a program that has to process uncompressed PCM files by using Amplitude Modulation concept.

The problem I face now is that I get correct audio output on the right channel and complete noise on the left.

I'm aware of interleaved format of stereo PCM files and If I want to modulate sound on both channels I just have to process every sample. Any advice?
This is my code:

```
import threading
import pyaudio
import struct
import numpy as npy
import wave

CHUNK = 1  # Number of samples to read
modulator_frequency: float = 12800.0  # Modulation frequency in Hz

# input_file = input(r"Specify *.wav audio file: ")
# data = wave.open(input_file, "rb")

data = wave.open("walk on air.wav", "rb")

pya = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Load PyAudio module

audio_stream = pya.open(format=pya.get_format_from_width(data.getsampwidth()),
                        channels=data.getnchannels(),
                        rate=data.getframerate(),
                        output=True)


def play_stream():
    bytestream = data.readframes(CHUNK)

    t = 1  # Iterating sample number

    while bytestream:  # Play until bytestream ends
        x = struct.unpack(b'<i', bytestream)[0]  # Convert b'\x01\x00\xfd\xff' to some friendly numbers
        # print(x)
        y = int(x * npy.sin(2 * npy.pi * modulator_frequency * t / data.getframerate()).astype(npy.float32))
        # y = x
        t += 1
        z = struct.pack(b'<i', y)  # Convert friendly numbers back to bytestream
        # print(bytestream, " ---> ", x, " ---> ", y, " ---> ", z)
        bytestream = data.readframes(CHUNK)
        audio_stream.write(z)


if data.getsampwidth() == 3:
    sample_type = "24 Bit Integer PCM"
elif data.getsampwidth() == 2:
    sample_type = "16 Bit Integer PCM"
elif data.getsampwidth() == 1:
    sample_type = "8 Bit Integer PCM"
else:
    sample_type = "Unknown - {}".format(data.getsampwidth())

print("Format:", sample_type)
print("Number of audio samples:", data.getnframes())
print("Number of audio channels:", data.getnchannels())
print("Duration:", round(data.getnframes() / data.getframerate(), 3), "Seconds")
print("Sample rate:", data.getframerate(), "Hz")

threading.Thread(play_stream()).start()

print("Playback ended successfully.")

audio_stream.stop_stream()
audio_stream.close()
pya.terminate()
```